# elasticsearch java client parse aggregation json query

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using `spring-data-elasticsearch` and I'm just wondering if it's somehow possible to send aggregation query as json string.

So the query looks like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "cspByState": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "properties.csp.keyword"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "levelType": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "level.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
          "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "wildcard": {
                  "event": {
                    "value": "input.start.*"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "event": {
                    "value": "input.finish.*"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "dateTime": {
              "gte": "2021-03-01T00:00Z",
              "lte": "2021-03-11T23:59:59.99Z",
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried to do following but it's always failing on unknown aggregation:

```
final WrapperQueryBuilder wrapper = new WrapperQueryBuilder(queryString);
final SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(wrapper);
searchSourceBuilder.size(0);
final SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("csp-index");
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

Flux.from(elasticsearchTemplate.execute(client -> client.aggregate(searchRequest))).collectList().block();
```

```
Caused by: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=named_object_not_found_exception, reason=[2:11] unknown field [aggs]]]
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.innerFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:496)
```

Answer (score 0):

with these lines

```java
final SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(wrapper);
searchSourceBuilder.size(0);
```

you set the `query` part of the search request and the `size` part. You cannot pass in the whole search request as query parameter.

The Aggregation must be set with

```java
searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(aggregationBuilder)
```

I don't know if Elasticsearch provides an `AggregationBuilder` that parses a JSON string, I did'nt see one when having a short look at the `AggregationBuilders`class.

Comment: at the end I did it with the code above, for now it works. Hopefully one day we will be able to use [SearchTemplate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html) that could solve all of this issues.

Comment: Just note it is still impossible to use JSON for aggregation with a new Elasticsearch Java API Client 8.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I did it with code below. The main thing was to send `typed_keys` query attribute to elastic and then get some methods from `DefaultReactiveElasticsearchClient` which do the response parsing.

```java
@Service
@Log4j2
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ElasticSearchService {
  
  private final ReactiveElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate;
  private final DfElasticSearchProperties elasticSearchProperties;
  private final Mustache.Compiler compiler;
  
  public Flux<Aggregation> transactionStatistics(LocalDate date) {
    final Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("dateFrom", date.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    parameters.put("dateTo", date.atTime(LocalTime.MAX).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    
    final String queryString = compiler.loadTemplate("transaction-statistics").execute(parameters);
    
    return aggregate(queryString);
  }
  
  private Flux<Aggregation> aggregate(String request) {
    return Flux.from(elasticsearchTemplate.execute(client -> sendRequest(client, request)));
  }
  
  private Flux<Aggregation> sendRequest(ReactiveElasticsearchClient client, String request) {
    return client.execute(c -> sendRequest(c, request))
             .flatMapMany(c -> c.body(BodyExtractors.toMono(byte[].class))
                                 .map(it -> new String(it, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                                 .flatMap(json -> getSearchResponseFromJson(json)))
             .flatMap(response -> Flux.fromIterable(response.getAggregations()));
  }
  
  private Mono<ClientResponse> sendRequest(WebClient client, String request) {
    return client.method(HttpMethod.GET).uri(
      builder -> builder.path("/").path(elasticSearchProperties.getCspEventsIndex()).path("/_search").queryParam(
        "typed_keys").build()).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).bodyValue(request).exchange();
  }
  
  private static Mono<SearchResponse> getSearchResponseFromJson(String jsonResponse) {
    try {
      XContentParser parser = createParser(jsonResponse);
      return Mono.just(SearchResponse.fromXContent(parser));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return Mono.error(new ElasticsearchException(String.format("Unable to parse response [%s]", jsonResponse), e));
    }
  }
  
  private static XContentParser createParser(String content) throws IOException {
    return XContentType.fromMediaTypeOrFormat(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) //
      .xContent() //
      .createParser(new NamedXContentRegistry(getDefaultNamedXContents()),
        DeprecationHandler.THROW_UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, content);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is still impossible to send an aggregation as JSON also with a Elasticsearch Java API Client 8. I finished with creating aggregation in my code and use only a query as JSON:

```java
NativeQuery query = NativeQuery.builder()
        // rewrite JSON aggregation into code
        .withAggregation("xxx",
            new Aggregation.Builder().terms(tb -> tb.field("field"))
                .build())
        .withQuery(new StringQuery(queryString))
        .withMaxResults(0)
        .build();

    Flux<Aggregation> aggregation = elasticsearchTemplate
        .aggregate(query, Object.class, IndexCoordinates.of("index-name"))
        .cast(ElasticsearchAggregation.class)
        .map(ElasticsearchAggregation::aggregation);
```

The API is a little strange because almost everywhere you can use a builder function (e.g. `Function<TermsAggregation.Builder, ObjectBuilder<TermsAggregation>> fn`). But
`withAggregation` takes only `Aggregation` instead of `Function<Aggregation.Builder, Aggregation.Builder>` so you have to call `build()`.